# Vim Spell, how to Not check spelling inside comments

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I use Vim Spell to check many LaTeX files, which get identified as `ft=plaintex`.  They are mostly regular text words, without markup syntax.  In many cases I have entire paragraphs without syntax.  Occasionally I do have markup, like `\dosomething`

Vim Spell skips checking my special commands, like `\dosomething` exactly as desired... except inside comments.  I don't want `\dosomething` checked there either.

If I find a paragraph I don't like, I comment the paragraph out with a **%** percent sign.  However, if I do that, then my markup syntax gets flagged as spelled wrong.  `\dosomething` then gets flagged as bad spelling "dosomething" spelled wrong.  I want Vim Spell to skip over `\dosomething` even if it's within a commented out paragraph. I could `zg`   the word in normal mode while using `:set spell`  but I'd rather Spell just skip my LaTeX syntax automatically, both in comments and outside of comments.

Is there a way I can tell Vim to skip flagging syntax words inside of my comments?  Another similar question explains that Vim will check the comments for misspelled words. I know that.  I want to turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following command you can turn off spellchecking for all LaTeX comments:

```
:syntax match Comment /%[^"]\+$/ contains=@NoSpell
```